# Watching props passed from inside a child

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I am unable to get my head around the watching mechanism in Vue.

I have a parent component, which passes a Vehicle object to child component.

Vehicle:

```
{
  Number : 'some number', 
  Position: { lat: 'some lat', lng: 'some long', }
}
```

Now I have a timer which updates this object in parent. Child also reflects change. Inside child I am actually placing this vehicle object on map as a marker.

What I am trying to do here is to watch for change in the prop (vehicle) if it changes then I want to smoothly/animate marker to the newly updated position.

I tried to do:

```
watch: {

vehicle: function(newVal, oldVal){
 console.log('newVal'); 
}

},
```

It didn't work, didn't print anything. Do I have to make watcher in parent component to watch and do that animation? or a child can watch property passed to it?

EDIT:

Changing of Vehicle object in parent:

If am receiving data from a real time database, so what I do is, I have maintained a parent Array which I loop to show markers.

Now I loop array and match new data with it, and simply update values where updated.

// Some random positions

```
var positions = [
                    {
                        lat: 24.827393, lng: 67.021769,
                    },
                    {
                        lat: 24.827279, lng: 67.028294,
                    },
                    {
                        lat: 24.834947, lng: 67.024829,
                    },
                    {
                        lat: 24.835719, lng: 67.012825,
                    },
                    {
                        lat: 24.8274599, lng: 67.0322483,
                    },
                ];

                var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * positions.length - 1) + 1);



    this.vehicles[0].position.lat: positions[random].lat;
this.vehicles[0].position.lng: positions[random].lng;
```

Later I am binding it to my child components like this:

```
  <CustomMarker :key="vehicle.number" v-bind:vehicle="vehicle"
                      v-for="(vehicle, index) in vehicles"></CustomMarker>
```

Basically above array of random positions is just for testing my smooth movement, I'll be receiving same ordinates in real time when done.

Comment: How do you change `vehicle` object in parent component? Can you include that code?

Comment: I have updated some description please check

Comment: Please include code, I think it's reactivity issue, but it's difficult to help without see these code.

Comment: put it in **updated** instead of **watch**
refer to: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your watcher will only respond to changes directly to the `vehicle` prop, *not* changes made to properties of the `vehicle` object or its descendants. What I mean is, if the parent component mutates the vehicle object like:

```js
this.vehicle.Position.lat = 123
```

and `this.vehicle` is bound to the `vehicle` prop of the child component, then the watcher will not be triggered because it's still the same `vehicle` object instance.

If the parent did this instead:

```js
this.vehicle = someOtherVehicle
```

then the watcher will be triggered.

You can instruct Vue to watch for changes to properties of the `vehicle` object (and descendants) by setting `deep` to true:

```js
watch: {
  vehicle: {
    deep: true,
    handler(newVal, oldVal) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

See [`watch` docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) for more information.

---

If you want to know the old and new latitude and longitude values, then one way is watch the `Position` property in the child, mutate the `Position` property in the parent, and keep the `{ lat, lng }` object immutable:

**Child**

```
watch: {
  'vehicle.Position'(oldVal, newVal) {
    const oldLat = oldVal.lat
    const newLat = newVal.lat
  }
}
```

**Parent**

```
// When you want to update the vehicle's position...
this.vehicle.Position = { lat: 123, lng: 456 }
```

Comment: Yes I understand this part, the problem here is that when I use deep watcher, it gives me save value in both params. newVal and oldVal are same.

Comment: Yes, `newVal` and `oldVal` still refer to the same object instance so the values will be the same. Vue doesn't take a deep snapshot of both objects before and after the mutation for performance reasons.

Comment: So how should I fix this?

Comment: LESSON LEARNED: Never mutate properties individually where object manipulation is possible. Thanks